# Drawing several graphs from a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I made a code like below. I would like there to be as many charts as are selected in the ListBox. Now they are always drawn all of them. For example, I would like to select listBox1 is one graph and e.g. listBox1, listBox2, listBox3 are 3 graphs.

How to change it or what to add?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   listBox1.Items.Add("value1");
   listBox1.Items.Add("value2");
   listBox1.Items.Add("value3");
   listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
}
```

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   connect.Open();
   string mysql = "SELECT value1, value2, value3, valuedate FROM mydata";
   MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysql, connect);
  
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
  
   chart1.Series["value1"].XValueMember = "valuedate";
   chart1.Series["value1"].YValueMembers = "value1";
  
   chart1.Series["value2"].XValueMember = "valuedate";
   chart1.Series["value2"].YValueMembers = "value2";
  
   chart1.Series["value3"].XValueMember = "valuedate";
   chart1.Series["value3"].YValueMembers = "value3";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your query based on the items selected in the list view and then also similarly add the series.

The below code will give you an idea of how to approach it.

```
string query = "SELECT valuedate ";

            for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                string value = listView1.SelectedItems[i].Text;
                query += ", " + value;
                chart1.Series.Add(value);
                chart1.Series[value].XValueMember = "valuedate";
                chart1.Series[value].YValueMembers = value;
            }

            query += " FROM mydata";
```